# How to set NSString value to NSMutable dictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring, nsdictionary

I am implementing web-service APIs, data content type is of JSON. The body of the request should be  in a string format i.e in double quotes but when I set it in a dictionary, I get the below result. Could anyone help me to set the NSString as string value in dictionary.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *reqParams = [NSMutableDictionary new]; 
[reqParams setObject:@"Data.SourceStreamRequest"forKey:@"_type"]; 

NSMutableDictionary *reqParams1 = [NSMutableDictionary new];  
[reqParams1 setObject:@"newmjpegdataSession"forKey:@"_type"];
       NSLog(@"%@:%@",reqParams,reqParams1);
```

**Output**

```
{
    "_type" = "Data.SourceStreamRequest";
}:{
    "_type" = newmjpegdataSession;
}
```

Could anyone help me to figure out the reason why ,the dictionary values are shown with double quotes and without double quotes.
Thank you

Comment: Because 1st one contains `.` in it.

Comment: How could I set the second string as NSString in dictionary.

Comment: Its setting a NSString not any other value.

Comment: I want newmjpegdataSession as "newmjpegdataSession",but I could not achieve this result after many trials. How to get encapsulate the text in "".?

Comment: Why you need to encapsulate the value in "" ? It is a NSString still.

Comment: Only if i send the data as "newmjpegdataSession" , i get the correct server response else it shows Error code 415-bad content type. How to achieve the result as "newmjpegdataSession".

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSJSONSerialization` to serialize your dictionary. Try this:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"_type", @"Data.SourceStreamRequest",
                                @"_type", @"newmjpegdataSession", nil];

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *resultAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"json:\n%@", resultAsString);
```

**Output:**

> json:  { "newmjpegdataSession" : "_type",   "Data.SourceStreamRequest"
>   : "_type"  }

Comment: I am getting the resultAsString value like this     [
  "newmjpegdataSession"
]  , i need it as dictionary value.More over object should be "newmjpegdataSession" and key should be "_type"

Comment: This is my requirement:  NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"newmjpegdataSession",@"_type",nil];   NSError *error;NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
  NSString *resultAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"json:\n%@", resultAsString);
   NSMutableDictionary *reqParams1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  [reqParams1 setObject:resultAsString forKeyedSubscript:@"keyvalue"];
But reqparams not in expected result

Comment: My expected result for reqParams1 is { "_type"="newmjpegdatasession"}

Comment: @SMS My answer is correct, I have no idea what you are trying to do or if you are implementing the answer correctly.